# Evenly Distribute Value Across Set of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to find a way to distribute a given amount across a variable number of rows.   In the example below the amount is fixed

```
Set @Amt = 1000
```

to get the number of rows

```
Set @AmtofRows = select count(*) from <table>

Set @AmtPerRow = @Amt / @AmtofRows
```

This is not working because @AmtofRows does not divide evenly into @Amt.  For example if @Amt = 1000 and @AmtofRows = 18 then @AmtPerRow would be 55.56...when this amount is applied to all 18 rows the total is 1000.08 the sum should not exceed 1000.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the datatype of `@Amt`?

Comment: Also, can you supply some example data to illustrate your question? Why do you think it should be `1000`? You are hitting some rounding "errors" in your multiplication. 55.56 * 18 = 1000.08, 18/1000 isn't really 55.56; it's 55.5555555........  If you enter 55.55555... as many 5s as your calculator will hold, then multiply that by 18, you'll end up with 999.9999999........ which will round up to 1000. Again, rounding is causing your discrepancy.

Comment: Amt is a numeric(10,2)...yes the issue is rounding...understood.  Unfortunately the legacy system this needs to be inserted into only carries 2 decimal places so the sum total has to match the original @Amt exactly.

Comment: The sum total can't exactly match the original amount if there is rounding in the sums.@TheImpaler's answer is probably the best way to handle this, though it's going to be slighly imprecise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic technique is to allocate the values to the rows, in a temp table or CTE. Then you need to sum the values of the amounts, and find the difference between the sum and the initial amount, and allocate that difference to ensure that the sums add up right. The simplest way is to add difference from the sum to one row, like this

```
DECLARE @Amount float = 1000;
DECLARE @Count int = (Select Count(RowID) from Test);

With Data as (
Select RowID, --Unique Row ID
    Round(@Amount / @Count, 2) as Val1, -- The calculated amount, rounded to cents
    row_number() over (ORDER BY RowID) as RowNo --A rowno for each result (so we can pick just one row later)
from Test
), SumData as (
Select SUM(Val1) as ValSum from Data  --Sum the allocated amounts
)
--This returns the allocated values, but on row 1, we adjust it
Select RowID, Val1 - case when RowNo = 1 then (Select Round(@Amount - ValSum, 2) from SumData) else 0 end as Val2
From Data;
```

You would then use this Val2 figure to actually update your table, or whatever you are doing with it. The biggest adjustment will be half the number of rows in cents. If putting all this on one row is not acceptable, and you want to spread the rounding error over the rows, then you would need to do a bit more processing.

Also, as an aside, are you sure you are supposed to evenly spread the amount over all the rows? Often in a case like this you should be spreading the value over the rows based on some amount in the rows - ie if you have value of 200 in one row and 100 in the others, the 200 row would get twice as much. To do this you would sum up the row values, then each row gets Amount * RowValue/TotalRowValues. It doesn't matter to this question, though, because rounding can still cause the numbers to not add up to the full amount, so you would still need to allocate the rounding error as above.

---

EDITED TO ADD

If you want to split the rounding error across as many lines as possible, then first allocate the amounts and sum to get the difference as above. Get the rounding error amount you still need to allocate, ie Round(@Amount - ValSum, 2). Multiply this number by 100, which will give you the number of rows that need a one cent difference added/subtracted from their amounts to make it all add up correctly. This number will always be less than the number of rows, because each row can only have at most 1/2 cent rounding error.

For example if the rounding error was -2.72, then 272 rows need 1 cent subtracted from their row amounts. If it was 2.72, then they need 1 cent added. I would use a temp table, not a CTE, with RowID, Amount to allocate, and a rowno. Fill it in step one (same as the CTE, calculate the rounding error as above, then if there is a rounding error do something like this (I haven't run this, but it should be close)

```
Update TempTable Set AllocatedAmount = AllocatedAmount + case when @RoundingError > 0 then 0.01 else -0.01 end
Where RowNo <= (ABS(@RoundingError) * 100)  --No of rows to adjust
```

You could write this as one query as above without using a temp table, but it gets a lot harder to read that way. If you had to spread the rounding error out across all the rows, not bunch them up at the top, you would need to do some modulo arithmetic to figure out if a specific rowno should get adjusted or not.

Comment: This is really close to being correct...after reversing the sign in the case statement:  Val1 - case when RowNo = 1 then -(Select Round(@Amount - ValSum, 2) from SumData) else 0 end as Val2.  I did run into one problem in this scenairo...consider this example, Amt is 10000 and row count is 1833 the Val 2 amount for row 1 -2.72...one requirement is that each row has a positive value as close to each other as possible.  any suggestion on how to spread the rounding error over all the rows?

Comment: Yeah, sorry should have been plus the difference, not minus it. I'll edit the answer with some ideas on how to spread the difference across multiple rows

Comment: Excellent explanation...was able to get this working based on your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical accounting problem that I remember from the 90s.

The solution is pretty simple. Just do as you are doing for all rows, except the last one. For the last one, instead of using the value you computed, just put the difference with the total.

For example: Distribute $100.00 in "equally" 3 rows.

So, you divide $100.00 by 3. You get $33.33.

- Row 1: You put **$33.33**. Running total: $33.33
- Row 2: You put **$33.33**. Running total: $66.66
- Row 3: You put **$33.34**. That is: $100.00 - $66.66.

Comment: Agree...a typical accounting problem.  Unfortunately this logic only works if the allocation amount is less than the rounding difference.  Consider this scenario...if the Amt to allocate is 10000 and the row count is 1833 then 5.46 is the amount for each with a rounding error of 8.18...this means the last row would be negative 2.72...each row has to have a positive amount greater than 0.

Comment: Yes, you need to find the "best" **amount** that meets two conditions: 1) The remainder of the last row should be always positive or zero, and 2) it's the highest possible number. I would consider an iterative algorithm to try the amount starting on a celing value (as in your example), and then I would decrease it by 1 cent until the remainder is positive or zero.